# No puedo instalar paquetes con pip en python 3.8.3, windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, instalacion

verán de un momento a otro pip dejo de instalarme paquetes, uso la instrucción pip install Xpaquete y siempre me sale el mismo error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pythoncom (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for datatime
```

No entiendo la razón de estos errores, les agradecería mucho si pudieran tenderme una mano con esto.
Uso python 3.8.3 en windows 10, la version de pip es 20.1.1

Comment: Trata con : `python3 -m pip install 'paquete'` o si no, `pip -m install 'paquete'`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero el error sigue igual.

Comment: A mi me pasó lo mismo y tuve que reinstalarlo, te propongo que hagas lo mismo.

Comment: Puede ser que el paquete que estás buscando no tenga un binario para Windows. Por esa razón, mi instalación de Python en Windows la hago con Anaconda, que contiene la mayor parte de las librerías que requiero y muchas que no requiero y sus binarios para Windows. Podrías probar eso. Desinstalas Python, bajas Anaconda, y usas eso. Por cierto ¿que es `datatime`? ¿no será `datetime`?

Comment: Creo que no quieres instalar `datatime` sino `datetime` y seguramente ya lo trae tu distribución de Python

Comment: A ver si aparece por ahí "jorgesys" y explica por qué bajó mi respuesta, que de hecho, es la correcta para la "pregunta/comentario" que expone el compañero

Comment: En https://pypi.org, no aparecen ni `datatime` ni `pythoncom` (los dos paquetes de tu mensaje de error). ¿Qué comando corriste? Puede que el paquete que pediste dependía de estos otros, que no existen en PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

puedes tratar con este comando :

```
   python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade PACKAGE==VERSION.VERSION.VERSION
```

Comment: Trate con esta misma instrucción pero me devolvió un error muy similar: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PACKEGE==VERSION.VERSION.VERSION (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PACKEGE==VERSION.VERSION.VERSION